# Can you make a reference to an Excel cell with a variable address?

Tags: excel

Would it be possible to make a reference like A(2+2)? I know that formula doesn't work but how would you formulate something like that?

Comment: `=INDEX(A:A,2+2)`.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways:

one can use a volatile OFFSET:

```
=OFFSET(A2,2,0)
```

or another volatile function INDIRECT:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&ROW(A2)+2)
```

or better yet the non volatile INDEX:

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROW(A2)+2)
```

Volatile functions should not be used in mass.  They will recalculate every time a change is made in Excel and that can greatly impact the user experience.  The INDEX will only recalc if the data in Column A on the sheet reference changes.  Thus cutting the number of superfluous calculation.

Comment: Thank you, how can you call the INDEX function to get the cell from another sheet? Something that would replicate =Sheet1!INDEX(A:A,ROW(A2)+2)?

Comment: `=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,ROW(A2)+2)`

Comment: INDIRECT may also be useful, depending on what you are trying to accomplish.